# How to style a cell's children when exporting an html table to XLSX

Tags: javascript, excel, formatting, export-to-excel

How do you style cell child elements in the export process?

Given a foo table like this:

```
<table id="myTableName">
<thead id="myTableNameHdr"><tr><th style="background-color:navy;color:white;">Test<th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="myTableNameBod"><tr><td>
    Choose
    <span style="color:red">RED </span>
    or
    <span style="color:blue">BLUE </span>
    colors...
    <td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

How can I render the red and blue text in the cell in a way that translates for excel.  Using inline styles works well for the *cell level* styles as i have it in my foo header row. However, the inner text styles are dropped. I realize this could be a by product of getting the text attribute vs iterating the children in the lib I'm using. Is there an alternative?

---

I am using a js that I inherited and I do not have the non-minified version :( I'm hoping someone knows who's it is. Maybe someone might recognize it.

Portion of formatted min.js code: (did not include all of it because >35K lines total)

```
if (!Object.keys) {
Object.keys = (function () {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({
            toString: null
        })
            .propertyIsEnumerable("toString"),
        dontEnums = ["toString", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "constructor"],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;
    return function (obj) {
        if (typeof obj !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function" || obj === null) {
            throw new TypeError("Object.keys called on non-object");
        }
        var result = [];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
                result.push(prop);
            }
        }
        if (hasDontEnumBug) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
                if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
                    result.push(dontEnums[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
})();
}
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
Array.prototype.filter = function (fun) {
    if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in t) {
            var val = t[i];
            if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t)) {
                res.push(val);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
};
}
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
};
}
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
Array.prototype.forEach = function (fun) {
    if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in t) {
            fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
        }
    }
};
}
if (!Array.prototype.map) {
Array.prototype.map = function (callback, thisArg) {
    var T, A, k;
    if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
        throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }
    if (thisArg) {
        T = thisArg;
    }
    A = new Array(len);
    k = 0;
    while (k < len) {
        var kValue, mappedValue;
        if (k in O) {
            kValue = O[k];
            mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
            A[k] = mappedValue;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return A;
};
}
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement, fromIndex) {
    if (this === undefined || this === null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }
    var length = this.length >>> 0;
    fromIndex = +fromIndex || 0;
    if (Math.abs(fromIndex) === Infinity) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    }
    if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex += length;
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            fromIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    for (; fromIndex < length; fromIndex++) {
        if (this[fromIndex] === searchElement) {
            return fromIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
}
if (!Array.isArray) {
Array.isArray = function (obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
};
}
"use strict";
if (typeof ArrayBuffer !== "undefined" && !ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice) {
ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice = function (begin, end) {
    begin = (begin | 0) || 0;
    var num = this.byteLength;
    end = end === (void 0) ? num : (end | 0);
    if (begin < 0) {
        begin += num;
```

Deeper snippet same file:

```
 var HTML_ = (function () {
    function html_to_sheet(str, _opts) {
        var opts = _opts || {};
        if (DENSE != null && opts.dense == null) {
            opts.dense = DENSE;
        }
        var ws = opts.dense ? ([]) : ({});
        var i = str.indexOf("<table"),
            j = str.indexOf("</table");
        if (i == -1 || j == -1) {
            throw new Error("Invalid HTML: missing <table> / </table> pair");
        }
        var rows = str.slice(i, j)
            .split(/(:?<tr[^>]*>)/);
        var R = -1,
            C = 0,
            RS = 0,
            CS = 0;
        var range = {
            s: {
                r: 10000000,
                c: 10000000
            },
            e: {
                r: 0,
                c: 0
            }
        };
        var merges = [],
            midx = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
            var row = rows[i].trim();
            if (row.substr(0, 3) == "<tr") {
                ++R;
                C = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (row.substr(0, 3) != "<td") {
                continue;
            }
            var cells = row.split("</td>");
            for (j = 0; j < cells.length; ++j) {
                var cell = cells[j].trim();
                if (cell.substr(0, 3) != "<td") {
                    continue;
                }
                var m = cell,
                    cc = 0;
                while (m.charAt(0) == "<" && (cc = m.indexOf(">")) > -1) {
                    m = m.slice(cc + 1);
                }
                while (m.indexOf(">") > -1) {
                    m = m.slice(0, m.lastIndexOf("<"));
                }
                var tag = parsexmltag(cell.slice(0, cell.indexOf(">")));
                CS = tag.colspan ? +tag.colspan : 1;
                if ((RS = +tag.rowspan) > 0 || CS > 1) {
                    merges.push({
                        s: {
                            r: R,
                            c: C
                        },
                        e: {
                            r: R + (RS || 1) - 1,
                            c: C + CS - 1
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (!m.length) {
                    C += CS;
                    continue;
                }
                m = unescapexml(m)
                    .replace(/[\r\n]/g, "");
                if (range.s.r > R) {
                    range.s.r = R;
                }
                if (range.e.r < R) {
                    range.e.r = R;
                }
                if (range.s.c > C) {
                    range.s.c = C;
                }
                if (range.e.c < C) {
                    range.e.c = C;
                }
                if (opts.dense) {
                    if (!ws[R]) {
                        ws[R] = [];
                    }
                    if (Number(m) == Number(m)) {
                        ws[R][C] = {
                            t: "n",
                            v: +m
                        };
                    } else {
                        ws[R][C] = {
                            t: "s",
                            v: m
                        };
                    }
                } else {
                    var coord = encode_cell({
                        r: R,
                        c: C
                    });
                    if (Number(m) == Number(m)) {
                        ws[coord] = {
                            t: "n",
                            v: +m
                        };
                    } else {
                        ws[coord] = {
                            t: "s",
                            v: m
                        };
                    }
                }
                C += CS;
            }
        }
        ws["!ref"] = encode_range(range);
        return ws;
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it can be done as long as you pay for the pro version.